# Not able to apply changes for wireless driver in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, intel, ubuntu-drivers, migration

I had asked this question in stack overflow(by mistake) , later on it was migrated to stack exchange superuser community a few days back (by some user). The link is pasted below.

https://superuser.com/questions/1557801/not-able-to-apply-changes-for-wireless-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04

I have a wireless network unclaimed issue in ubuntu 20.04. For which I would like to get some solutions. Since I am not getting much answers there I wanted the askubuntu community to know about my problem and so I am attaching the link here. Also I would appreciate if the above thread of mine is moved to askubuntu community as well.

[Additional Drivers - wireless option disabled by default (not able to enable)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU4yE.png)

Also the propreitary drivers options are turned on (Refer image below)

[Proprietary Drivers for devices - option is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zrzo.png)

Here are following commands that are added for the edits suggested.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 
8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Another output from my computer for the following command.

```
$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi

$ dmesg | grep iwl

[    2.560256] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.731006] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Not getting any output for *sudo modprobe iwlwifi* command

Liux Kernel Version is

```
$ uname -a

Linux aadithya-Precision-5520 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am sure there is no problem with the wifi adapter . Since I am using ubuntu along with a dual boot Windows 10 OS and there is no wifi problem there.

Many Thanks

Regards

Aadithya

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and also: `dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`. This device should work. Please also add output of `modinfo iwlwifi`

Comment: The device may be broken too. Do you have Windows? Does it work there?

Comment: Yes it is working in Windows 10

Comment: "Since I am using ubuntu along with a dual boot Windows 10 OS and there is no wifi problem there." Could this be the problem? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: @Pilot6 .. I am not getting any output when I use the sudo modprobe iwlwifi command

Comment: @chili555 .. That's interesting. Let me give it a try

Comment: Try to shutdown Windows properly. Disable Fast start feature and shut it down. Windows doesn't shutdown by default but hibernates. This cause trouble with some devices.

Comment: I just tried @Pilot6 , chili555 . After I disabled the fast startup option in Windows. I tried to boot into Ubuntu and the booting failed. When I re-enabled the fast startup option in Windows, then I am able to boot into Ubuntu which is quite weird.

Comment: Can you elaborate "the booting failed"?

Comment: I did the following steps 
1. Went into Windows - Disabled the fast start-up option . And Shut down windows
2. Again after starting my system. The grub menu appeared for me to choose the OS to boot.
3. Chose Ubuntu and then the screen went blank. Did a force power off

4. Again I went into Windows to enable the fast start-up option. Now Ubuntu got booted properly. But still wifi is not working